# How can I regroup data in Excel?

Tags: excel, csv

I'm trying to regroup data in Excel from Statistics Canada census. I downloaded the CSV file from here: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/prof/details/download-telecharger/comp/page_dl-tc.cfm?Lang=E

There are over 1,000,000 row but the problem is that instead of seeing the number of the dissemination area and then the data, there are like over 1,000 lines with the same dissemination area number and then the data.

E.g.

DA 24660001 : language: English

DA 24660001 : language: French

DA 24660001 : language: Spanish

DA 24660001 : language: German

DA 24660001 : language: Italian

DA 24660001 : language: Russian

Etc. etc. like 1000 times

I'd like to find a way to regroup those so I can get the

DA 24660001 on one side and then the languages on the other side, so I can finally get to DA 24660002 and DA 24660003 without having to browser through thousands of lines...

Can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: split the data with Text to Columns, or better yet, use Power Query to open the CSV, then clean up the data to suit your purpose.